# Load on bed of pickup for extended period of time

Tags: toyota, suspension, truck, tacoma, payload

I just got a Toyota Tacoma 2012 Sport long bed. I'm an artist and I make driftwood horse sculptures. I have two horses on the bed of the truck currently which comes to about 500 lbs. I intend to cruise around NYC to show my horses to a few clients for the entire weekend. I'm wondering if it is bad for the truck's suspension to keep the load on for an extended period of time. Thanks!!

Comment: Not relevant to th e question. Could you upload a picture of your horse sculptures? Just curios :D

Comment: Can you upvote me answering your question?

Answer (score 8):

Your truck is designed to carry that load.  If you consider carrying a full set of passengers.  1 in the front, 3 in the back, that weight would exceed your current load of 500 pounds.  I would not be concerned at all regarding doing on what you plan on doing.  In fact, make it 1,000 pounds and do it, your truck would handle that just fine although it may accelerate slower and take a bit longer to stop.  Enjoy your new truck, I have a 2013 and put a lot of weight in regularly.  I pick up used motorcycles and fix them up frequently.  Recently I went to LA, picked up two of them, drove around town on city streets meeting up with friends and drove back to Phoenix.  It handled it just fine.

The official load for your vehicle is 1,465 pounds and the towing capacity is 3,300 pounds.

Best of luck to you.

Comment: Agreed that 500lbs is nothing for these vehicles. I believe the payload rating is a bit lower than that (as far as what Toyota puts out). They rate it at around [1,200-1,500 lbs](http://www.toyota.com/content/ebrochure/2013/tacoma_ebrochure.pdf) ... Auto/Man tranny will differ, plus payload includes driver/passengers as well.

Comment: I corrected the load and added the towing capacity.  thanks for calling that out.

Comment: Ok great! Thank you everyone for the help.. I would like to post a picture but I am new to this site.. How do I post a pic?

Comment: My Instagram is francocuttica check it out!